# bottle custom filter in mounting a url

Tags: python, bottle

How do I add a custom filter in mounting a URI path using Bottle instance?

```py
app = default_app()
app.mount('/tenant/<:re:Foo([0-9]+)>/foos', app=foos_api())
app.mount('/tenant/<:re:Bar[0-9]+)>/bars', app=bars_api())
```

Instead of the regex, I would like to add a custom filter in mount uri like below:

```py
app.mount('/tenant/<token:myFilter>/foos', app=foos_api())
```

But bottle did not allow it. How do I add a custom filter to validate and raise a custom HttpResponse while mounting a Uri?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Wildcard-filters](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#wildcard-filters) which available from version 0.10 .

**Example:**

```
 
app = Bottle()

def list_filter(config):
    ''' Matches a comma separated list of numbers. '''
    delimiter = config or ','
    regexp = r'\d+(%s\d)*' % re.escape(delimiter)

    def to_python(match):
        return map(int, match.split(delimiter))

    def to_url(numbers):
        return delimiter.join(map(str, numbers))

    return regexp, to_python, to_url

app.router.add_filter('list', list_filter)

@app.route('/follow/')
def follow_users(ids):
    for id in ids:
```

Comment: Thnx. This option is available with `route` and not with mount. I want to to use filter during mount.